# How to install Tascam US-322 under 14.04 lts Ubuntu Studio

Tags: 14.04, usb

This is my first time I ask a question here. 
I've just started using Ubuntu 14.04lts U, but I can't seem to get my sound card (Tascam US-322) up and running.

```
lsusb output:

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21b4 Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
    Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0644:8040 TEAC Corp. 
    Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 064e:f203 Suyin Corp.
```

Pluging the card in and checking the output of dmesg I get this:

```
[ 1307.763046] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci [ 1307.850271] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0644, idProduct=8040 [ 1307.850280] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 [ 1307.850286] usb 2-1.1: Product: US-322 [ 1307.850291] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: TASCAM [ 1307.850295] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: no serial number
```

Anyone?

Comment: If that's the ouput of lsusb you should mention that.

Comment: Plug the card in and check the output of `dmesg` see if you can see anything related to the sound card.

Comment: I added what you've told me to the question above. Thanks!